# WCF app.config overwrites WindowsService.exe.config

Tags: c#, .net, wcf, windows-services

I want a windows service to keep configuration paramters. Normaly I would just define them in the settings of VisualStudio so I can get them programatically with something like

```
String configParameter = Properties.Settings.Default.parameterName;
```

After the service is deployed and I need to change the configuration, I can simply stop the service, change the parameters in the Service.exe.config which is looking like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<configuration>
<configSections>
<sectionGroup name="applicationSettings" type="System.Configuration.ApplicationSettingsGroup, System, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089" >
        <section name="MyService.Properties.Settings" type="System.Configuration.ClientSettingsSection, System, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089" requirePermission="false" />
    </sectionGroup>
</configSections>
<startup> 
    <supportedRuntime version="v4.0" sku=".NETFramework,Version=v4.5" />
</startup>
<applicationSettings>
    <EAkteService.Properties.Settings>
        <setting name="parameterName" serializeAs="String">
            <value>I_am_a_parameter</value>
        </setting>
 </applicationSettings>
```

Then I would start the service again and it is using the updated parameters. I think this is the recommended aproach, but please correct me, if I am wrong on this.

Now my service needs to host a WCF library. As soon as I do that, the Service.exe.config is overwritten with the content of the app.config originating from the wcf lib and I can no longer set my configuration parameters for the origianl windows service.

What is the correct approach to be able to configure both, the wcf lib and the windows service through a config file, without having to recompile and redeploy the service?

Best regards.

Comment: You just continue to use **Service.exe.config** with your original and merged in values with whatever WCF library is trying to configure.  Both should be able to co-exist

Comment: I have already tried to append my configuration values, but that is aperently not working. I can read and set the values programatically but they are not read from the config file on program start.

Comment: Libraries don't use their own config file - they use the config file of the application that is using the library.  I'm rather confused at how your class library is overwriting the Window's Service config file, unless you're doing something programatically?